# how to import/export csv files to amazon s3 server

Tags: amazon-s3

I tries a lot for export/import product csv files to amazon server or ec2 instance but fails.

Does anyone knows how to import/export files to amazon s3 server bucket or its ec2 instance??

Comment: There is a tool called "s3cmd" that can do it.

Comment: but this will work for local.my website is on remote server from there i want to import and export files to amazon s3.

Answer (score 1):

The [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) is available for Windows, Mac and Linux. It has several relevant commands:

- `aws s3 cp` to copy files to/from Amazon S3
- `aws s3 sync` will synchronize files (only copying new/modified files)

These commands can be used to transfer files between an Amazon EC2 instance and an Amazon S3 bucket, or even between Amazon S3 buckets (even in different regions!). It can also be used on your own computer (outside of Amazon EC2) to transfer information to/from Amazon S3 buckets.

Here's a video with lots of demos: [Deep Dive: AWS Command Line Interface](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o33eXk26c1Y)